# Unity Mecanim - play animation in certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mecanim

Programming RPG game, I would like to control animation speed in relation to its duration.

For example, character has to cast spell in X seconds. I would like to play the animation state so fast so the animation is finished exactly in X seconds.

-X is determined right before starting an animation.

-I have multiple animations for multiple characters so I would like to avoid doing this via manual calculation and adjustment of animation clip speed in animator

**How can I implement this behavior?**

Comment: [Why “is this possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Comment: Thanks, edited the wording.

Comment: The problem is not the wording; to give directions we need to know both where you are now and where you are trying to go. Statements like “is this possible?”, “help me”, “how can I implement this?”, and so on do not do this.

Comment: I dont understand. I described pretty exact behavior that I aim for in Unity, but dont know how to implement. I also believe such question might be helpful to others in future. I am not trying to be disrespectful, but I dont get your point.

Comment: I already provided a link that explains in detail what is wrong with questions like these, why you are not getting any good answers, and exactly what you should be doing. Pay particularly close attention to the paragraph after “So what should be asked instead?” Another good site explains why you should probably not ask a question until [after you have some code to show](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Answer (score 1):

You could change the speed of the animator component. The thing is that you should update the speed on each iteration of the game loop (or every Y time).

Animation speed may be [0-1] where 1 is default. You'll need to take the length of the animation and do some calculation base on your X and the animation.

Something like:
`float length = gameObject.animation.clip.length;`

`newSpeed = ....`

https://answers.unity.com/questions/902029/how-to-get-and-change-animation-speed-of-animator.html

Comment: gameObject.animation.clip.length is for old animation system I think? Doing that seem much more complicated in Mecanim.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/692593/get-animation-clip-length-using-animator.html

Comment: @Immersive Yes, that manages to do it, but as EvilWarren pointed out in that thread, in doesnt work on the frame you switch the animation (which is the frame you want to get the info) which brings whole set of new problems.